# Send email apexclass triggered by procesbuilder

Tags: apex, email, process-builder, invocable-method

Im very new to apex but I have managed to write a class that is been called by a button on the lead object to send outbound emails with attachments which works. I want to get rid of the button and use processbuilder to invoke the Method. I get the error only static methods can be invocable, when I use static I get the error that a constructor cant be static how di I make this work, here is my code:

```
public class SendemailController {

public String LeadId {get;set;}
@InvocableMethod
Public SendemailController(){
 LeadId ='00Q0Y000004d5l2UAA'; /** ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); **/
 }

Public Pagereference sendEmailFunction(){
 Lead getEmail = [SELECT Id, Email_Klant__c FROM Lead WHERE id=:LeadId];
   if(getEmail.Email_Klant__c != null) {
     String toaddress = getEmail.Email_Klant__c;

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {toaddress};
String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {toaddress};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo(toaddress);
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Name');
mail.setSubject('Testing email through apex');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setUseSignature(true);
mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear tester, here are the attechments. This mail is sent trough apex');

List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();        
 for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :LeadId]){
   Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
   efa.setFileName(a.Name);
   efa.setBody(a.Body);
   fileAttachments.add(efa);
 }    

mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
  PageReference reference = new PageReference('https://XXXXXXXXXXX.cs84.my.salesforce.com/'+ LeadId);
  reference.setRedirect(true);
  return reference;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using controller class to use for Invocation.

You have used `@InvocableMethod` annotation on Constructor. That's why the error is.

You need a static method which could be used for invocation and that shouldn't be Constructor.

```
public class SendemailController {
  @InvocableMethod
  public static void sendEmailFunction() {

  }
}
```

Refer [InvocableMethod Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)

*There will be other issues could popup during your development, so raise separate questions for that.*